# Turn on exception handling in visual studio 2010 by default for all projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

It seems that visual studio 2010 does not break on thrown exceptions by default for new projects - you have to go into the settings and turn that behavior on. This setting seems to be a per-project setting, rather than a system-wide one.

Is there any way to force the default behavior to be to break on thrown exceptions for all new projects?

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, on windows 7 Professional, on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Do you mean it isn't setup to _break_ on all exceptions? Exceptions are thrown by your application, not VS.

Comment: @Oded, yes, but the actual dialog In question (Debug->Exceptions) uses the word "Thrown" as well...

Comment: Yes, thrown _by the application_.

Comment: Only one kind of programming style ever requires this: http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/13181756185

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is clearly Bullshit.

Comment: No. It makes perfect sense. That's exactly what that setting represents.

Comment: If you firmly want it, Recording a macro could make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean the `Debug\Exceptions...` menu dialog to catch all first chance exceptions, this is global/system-wide.

(Note that like many global settings, I *think* its value is saved when VS shuts down, and so beware if you have multiple instances of VS open with different values for this setting.)

Comment: On My machine, this is a project-wide setting. If I create a new project, the default is to not throw these exceptions. If I turn them all on, save the project, close VS, create a new project I find that once again, they are all off. If I then open the first project, guess what? They're back on.

Comment: Maybe it's solution-wide then?  I'm pretty sure it's not project-scoped, but maybe it's solution-scoped.

Comment: Possibly. In either case, surely there's a way to change the default setting! It seems to me that turning off exceptions by default is an utterly braindead thing to do.

Comment: 'turning off exceptions'? It breaks on unhandled exceptions - just not all thrown exceptions, handled or unhandled. Exceptions are not 'turned off', they bubble up precisely as you'd expect and just trigger a break only when they're unhandled.

Answer (score 3):

It's loaded first time from the Registry here (and after that persisted in the solution):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio[VS version]\Configuration\AD7Metrics\Exception{449EC4CC-30D2-4032-9256-EE18EB41B62B}\Common Language Runtime Exceptions\[namespace]\[exception type name]

**[VS Version]** can be 9.0 or 10.0 or any other hive (like 9.0Exp if your running in VS 2008 SDK experimental hive)

**[namespace]** can be for example System and **[exception type name]** System.AppDomainUnloadedException.

Then you must setup the **State** key value (make it consistent with other existing exceptions configuration).

Comment: I found this as well, but found that the values reset after every use. If you set these, then create a new project, then shut down all VS instances, do the values reset?

Comment: I tried this with the Managed Debugging Assistant for LoaderLock and the check box is unchecked in the dialog but the assistant still pops up...

Comment: I have clearly not the intention to help anyone on this because nothing thinks it's interesting since it has 0 votes :-)